# Are questions about the historical development of languages on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I think the title says it all, but let me elaborate.

I would like to ask which languages have been known at certain time. Maybe one could elaborate the question by focusing on a special region or place, even if that wouldn't be may primary goal. Of course by known at a certain time I will mean that we have historical proofs of that and that a large amount of the population would speak/use them.

But are questions on "the history languages or language development/derivation" on-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say they are.

There are a couple of caveats though:

1. There is another stack for linguistics. Depending on what you are asking, you might have better luck asking there.
2. This stack doesn't like vague questions and is *very* quick to close. For example, a question based of the first sentence of your second paragraph would be almost hopeless. *Every* language is known to someone, two people actually, or its not much of a language.

Comment: 1. I've seen it and might have forgotten it. 2. I know this by experience ;) and hope to find a good formulation!

Comment: Can I ask this question "again" on linguistics meta or will that be considered as cross posting?

Comment: T.E.D., FYI they're not to be called "stacks" anymore. SE was never behind that slang in the first place, and now they're pushing for them to be called "sites" exclusively. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210961/keeping-the-top-bar-logged-in#comment677415_210961